# hapi and node.js to create a REST API Server

Tags: node.js, api, rest, restify, hapi.js

I wish to build a web service with lots of data updates and reads and user authentication.

*Which one is a better choice among [hapi](https://npmjs.org/package/hapi), [restify](https://npmjs.org/package/restify), or express for a Rest API?*
Please feel free to suggest any other framework which I haven't yet stumbled upon.

After a lot of searching, all the tutorials I could find were using the *hapi framework pre v2.0*. *Could you please suggest me some good tutorials on using hapi and node.js to build a web  API server?*

I am using *MongoDB* for the data.

Comment: I did research on this, and replied to someone that had a similar question as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469767/how-do-express-and-hapi-compare-to-each-other/31223294#31223294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hapi is great, one of the most famous successful implementation was the back-end system of Walmart US, and it survived the Black Friday... Search on YouTube for: "taking a REST and being HAPI"

https://github.com/geek/hapi-example

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-hapi-create-rest-api

Answer (score 4):

I also found the following very helpful -

- [hapi hapi joi joi](http://hueniverse.com/2013/01/hapi-hapi-joi-joi/)
- [HAPI API Reference](http://hapijs.com/api)